# Highchart legend issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to make chart legend outside of the chart. in the bottom.
but `floating: false` doesn't seem to work.

[image]

can someone help me to handle this?

```
chart: { 
        style: {
             fontFamily: 'Dosis',
             // height: 200,
             backgroundColor: 'lightgreen'
        },
        backgroundColor: null,                  
         spacingBottom: 0,
         spacingTop: 0,
         spacingLeft: 0,
         spacingRight: 0,
         marginBottom: 75,
         marginTop: 15,
         marginLeft: 40,
         marginRight: 10
},              
legend: {
    layout: 'horizontal',
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    y: 0,
    floating: false,
     itemMarginTop: 3,
     maxHeight: 100,
     navigation: {
        animation: true
     },
    itemHiddenStyle: '#4f7b3f',
    itemStyle: {
         fontSize: 14                
      }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Create http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Your `marginBottom` is to low. It is set to 75, but legend height is set to 100. In short: increase `marginBottom`.